# Count messages in an msmq sub-queue

Tags: count, msmq

Is there any way (C# or native) of counting the messages in a message queue (sub queue).
Using a queue name of "DIRECT=OS:slc11555001\private$\file-queue;retry"

I want to know how many messages are in the sub queue. At the moment I can see using the management console that there are in fact messages in that queue. If the OS can do it, so should I.

MQMgmtGetInfo returns 0xc00e0020 (which is not a documented error code).

I am therefore confused.
I am using code from here:
http://functionalflow.co.uk/blog/2008/08/27/counting-the-number-of-messages-in-a-message-queue-in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is as follows (from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304287):
MQ_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMATNAME_OPERATION (0xC00E0020).
MQMgmtGetInfo won't understand the subqueue format name.

The retry subqueue only really exists as a logical division of private$\file-queue queue.
You can call a count on the file-queue but not subqueues within it.

Cheers
John

Comment: So using this method, there is no way of getting the count of messages in the retry and journal queues?

Comment: Subqueues - not as far as I can tell. Journal queues should be fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

From [the MSDN page on subqueues:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711414.aspx)

> Subqueues are created implicitly, so only the following APIs can be
>   used with subqueues: MQOpenQueue, MQCloseQueue, MQCreateCursor,
>   MQReceiveMessage, MQReceiveMessageByLookupId, MQHandleToFormatName,
>   MQMoveMessage, and MQPathNameToFormatName. **Calling any of the other
>   Message Queuing APIs returns an error**